# How to restore fonts after kubuntu-desktop?

Tags: fonts, kde

I've installed and deleted kubuntu-desktop just to look what KDE is, and so on, and now even in Unity some fonts are totally ugly :( Specially in Firefox, I have real eyeache after reading sites with these fonts. How to restore them like it was before?

Answer (score 3):

This fixed it for me:

Change the content of the file $HOME/.fonts.conf to:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<match target='font'>
<edit name='autohint' mode='assign'>
<bool>true</bool>
</edit>
</match>
</fontconfig>
```

Then restart firefox.

Comment: +1, this fixed things for me. Combined with "Use sub-pixel rendering" and "Slight" Hinting style in the Fonts -> Configure Anti-Alias Settings dialog, makes the fonts look normal again.